# Apply (cosine) similarity measure over a datatable

Tags: r, data.table, apply, similarity, cosine-similarity

I am looking for a sensible way of determining the similarity between project team members who have all been scored on four dimensions.

A data excerpt has been added here below and a slightly larger example is added at the end of the question in dput

```
pnum invid dom_st prim_st pat_st net_st
 1: 7265873 24104      0       1      1      0
 2: 7266757 38775      1       2      2      3
 3: 7266757 38776      1       2      2      3
 4: 7268524 34281      1       3      2      2
 5: 7268524 34282      1       3      2      2
 6: 7272620 20002      0       1      2      0
 7: 7272620 22284      0       1      2      0
 8: 7273253 31921      1       1      1      4
 9: 7273253 31922      1       1      1      4
10: 7283628 26841      1       1      1      2
11: 7283628 26843      1       1      1      2
12: 7289442 17763      2      11     48     10
13: 7289442 17764      2      11     63      9
14: 7289525 38087      0       1      1      0
15: 7289525 38088      0       2      1      0
16: 7289525 38089      0       3      1      1
```

The goal is to create a similarity measure for each 'pnum' that compares the four last column values across all 'invid'. The number of 'invid' per 'pnum' varies between 2 and 26.

EDIT 1:
Concretely, for 'pnum' 7266757 (row 2 and 3) I want to similarity between th vector for invid 38775 (1,2,2,3) and invid 38776 (1,2,2,3) so this one should give a result of 1. For 'pnum' 7289525 (rows 14-16), I want the similarity between the three row-vectors (0,1,1,0), (0,2,1,0), and (0,3,1,1). This gives the below:

```
simil(matrix(c(0,1,1,0,0,2,1,0,0,3,1,1), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE), method = "cosine")
          1         2
2 0.9486833          
3 0.8528029 0.9438798
```

In a final step (could be a separate formula), I would like "to reduce" that matrix (for teams of n > 2) to a single value that ideally would be constrained between 0 and 1. A simple way of doing so would be to just take the mean of the matrix result but perhaps there is a smarter way?

I tried the following (with data stored in data.table 'dt' but that gave the below error:

```
library('proxy')    
sim <- dt[, simil(dt, method="cosine"), by = pnum]
    Error in .Call("R_cosine", c(4262069, 4262069, 4262069, 4273567, 4273567, : negative length vectors are not allowed
```

Any suggestion to more successfully apply this or a similar function to a data.table and creative ideas for how to reduce a similarity matrix to a single point value would be very welcome.

The total dataset is about 150,000 rows with about 92,000 projects 'pnum'.

```
structure(list(pnum = c(7265873, 7266757, 7266757, 7268524, 7268524, 
7272620, 7272620, 7273253, 7273253, 7283628, 7283628, 7289442, 
7289442, 7289525, 7289525, 7289525, 7301987, 7301987, 7305259, 
7305259, 7307986, 7307986, 7310332, 7310332, 7333490, 7333490, 
7333502, 7333502, 7414991, 7414991), invid = c(24104, 38775, 
38776, 34281, 34282, 20002, 22284, 31921, 31922, 26841, 26843, 
17763, 17764, 38087, 38088, 38089, 34843, 38412, 32514, 33946, 
28587, 28588, 17204, 17205, 28587, 28588, 28587, 28588, 37008, 
37009), dom_st = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), prim_st = c(1, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 11, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 5, 
5, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3), pat_st = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 48, 63, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 14, 14, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 1, 1), net_st = c(0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 4, 4, 2, 2, 10, 9, 
0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0)), .Names = c("pnum", 
"invid", "dom_st", "prim_st", "pat_st", "net_st"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000230788>)
```

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do. `simil(dt, method="cosine")`, if it is valid code, will evaluate to the same result in every `by=` group since you aren't actually using the subset of data associated with it...

Comment: Not sure if I understand your comment entirely @Frank. I am hoping to determine the cosine similarity matrix for each project 'pnum' between the different project members (column 'invid'). Applying the code using 'by = pnum' from 'data.table' package is too simplistic (which is why it does not work). I add a specification in the question to make the objective clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)

# find relevant columns for call to simil
cols <- stringr::str_subset(names(DT), "_st$")
cols
#[1] "dom_st"  "prim_st" "pat_st"  "net_st"

DT[, (mean(proxy::simil(.SD, method="cosine"))), .SDcols = cols, by = pnum]
#       pnum        V1
# 1: 7265873       NaN
# 2: 7266757 1.0000000
# 3: 7268524 1.0000000
# 4: 7272620 1.0000000
# 5: 7273253 1.0000000
# 6: 7283628 1.0000000
# 7: 7289442 0.9968006
# 8: 7289525 0.9151220
# 9: 7301987 1.0000000
#10: 7305259 1.0000000
#11: 7307986 1.0000000
#12: 7310332 1.0000000
#13: 7333490 1.0000000
#14: 7333502 1.0000000
#15: 7414991 1.0000000
```

Note: I need to wrap the `j` expression in parantheses. Without, I do get an error messages which I don't understand:

```
DT[, mean(proxy::simil(.SD, method="cosine")), .SDcols = cols, by = pnum]
```

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
>     Invalid column: it has dimensions. Can't format it. If it's the result of data.table(table()), use as.data.table(table()) instead.

#### Edit 1

If you want to get the similarity matrices for each `pnum` (before averaging them) I suggest to use `lapply()` which returns a list:

```
pnums <- DT[, unique(pnum)]
results <- lapply(pnums, function(x) {
  proxy::simil(DT[pnum == x, cols, with = FALSE], method="cosine")
})
setNames(results, pnums)
#$`7265873`
#simil(0)
#
#$`7266757`
#  1
#2 1
#
#$`7268524`
#  1
#2 1
#
#$`7272620`
#  1
#2 1
#
#$`7273253`
#  1
#2 1
#
#$`7283628`
#  1
#2 1
#
#$`7289442`
#          1
#2 0.9968006
#
#$`7289525`
#          1         2
#2 0.9486833          
#3 0.8528029 0.9438798
#
#$`7301987`
#  1
#2 1
#
#$`7305259`
#  1
#2 1
#
#$`7307986`
#  1
#2 1
#
#$`7310332`
#  1
#2 1
#
#$`7333490`
#  1
#2 1
#
#$`7333502`
#  1
#2 1
#
#$`7414991`
#  1
#2 1
```

#### Edit 2

The OP has added an additional requirement that he wants to compute a number of aggregate values for each `pnum`. This can be achieved by

```
DT[, {
  sim_mat <- proxy::simil(.SD, method="cosine")
  list(min = min(sim_mat), max = max(sim_mat), 
       mean = mean(sim_mat), sd = sd(sim_mat))
}, .SDcols = cols, by = pnum]
#       pnum       min       max      mean         sd
# 1: 7265873       Inf      -Inf       NaN         NA
# 2: 7266757 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000         NA
# 3: 7268524 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000         NA
# 4: 7272620 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000         NA
# 5: 7273253 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000         NA
# 6: 7283628 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000         NA
# 7: 7289442 0.9968006 0.9968006 0.9968006         NA
# 8: 7289525 0.8528029 0.9486833 0.9151220 0.05402336
# 9: 7301987 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000         NA
#10: 7305259 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000         NA
#11: 7307986 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000         NA
#12: 7310332 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000         NA
#13: 7333490 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000         NA
#14: 7333502 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000         NA
#15: 7414991 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000         NA
```

#### Data

```
DT <- structure(list(pnum = c(7265873, 7266757, 7266757, 7268524, 7268524, 
7272620, 7272620, 7273253, 7273253, 7283628, 7283628, 7289442, 
7289442, 7289525, 7289525, 7289525, 7301987, 7301987, 7305259, 
7305259, 7307986, 7307986, 7310332, 7310332, 7333490, 7333490, 
7333502, 7333502, 7414991, 7414991), invid = c(24104, 38775, 
38776, 34281, 34282, 20002, 22284, 31921, 31922, 26841, 26843, 
17763, 17764, 38087, 38088, 38089, 34843, 38412, 32514, 33946, 
28587, 28588, 17204, 17205, 28587, 28588, 28587, 28588, 37008, 
37009), dom_st = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), prim_st = c(1, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 11, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 5, 
5, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3), pat_st = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 48, 63, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 14, 14, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 1, 1), net_st = c(0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 4, 4, 2, 2, 10, 9, 
0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0)), .Names = c("pnum", 
"invid", "dom_st", "prim_st", "pat_st", "net_st"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

Comment: Hi Uwe, thanks for the proposed solution. I see you try to get the mean of the various cosinus similarity indices immediately, which could work (although I am not sure that the mean makes most sentence to determine how different people are) but taking the mean of the cosinus values of 'pnum' 7289525 (depicted in the OP, edit 1) results in a much lower value (0.545163) than what you find (0.9151220). So something seems incorrect...

Comment: `matrix()` uses the parameter `byrow = FALSE` by default but you have given the data row-wise without setting `byrow = TRUE`. `mean(proxy::simil(matrix(c(0,1,1,0,0,2,1,0,0,3,1,1), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE), method = "cosine")) returns 0.915122 like the `data.table` version.
`

Comment: Wow, it would have taken me 100 years to figure that out! thanks for the clarification. Thanks heaps. The list solution you suggest could work indeed but does not make for easy data handling later of course. I reckon I'll use min, mean, max, and sd all together to get a couple values I can work with. Thanks!